# cant play audio url with twilio play

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-node

i try to do a simple call phone from twilio that play a massage and hang up,
but no matter what url i put, when the call made i get a voice massage about function error
here is my code:

```
let twilio = require('twilio');

var accountSid =; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = ;   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;


const response = new VoiceResponse();
response.play({
    loop : 1,
},"https://scribie.com/records/7941e240b8884865872ac859e389927b78757fae_orig.mp3?fn=test2.mp3&to=FHtRpSzUlmmaVRWjl7n23mC3Ezm5nYwK");

console.log(response.toString());

client.calls
    .create({
        twiml: response.toString(),
        to: '',
        from: ''
    }).then(call => console.log(call.sid)).catch(e=>console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can get your code to work when I replace the Scribie URL with "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3". When I try to open up the Scribie URL you have, it takes me to this webpage one has to log-in to view. Instead of that, I'd try uploading the file to [Twilio Assets](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019105433-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Assets) or a different hosting service.